# Problem with Visualforce Page and Field Filters based on RecordType

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page, a standard controller and a custom controller extension working with a custom object called `Services__c`.

In the controller extension Constructor, I have the following code (this is abbreviated):

```
ctl=controller;
svc=(Services__c)ctl.getRecord();

//Get and set the record type id. 
RecordType rType = [Select Id from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Services__c' and DeveloperName = 'Internal' limit 1];
svc.RecordTypeId=rType.id;
```

The rest of the constructor sets various field values on `svc`, all of which appear when the page loads. The point is, the record type is set before the page is loaded and is then visible on the form (this shows the correct record type).

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Services__c.RecordTypeId}" />
```

One of the fields on the VF page (`Operated_By__c`) is a related object lookup with a  filter. The filter restricts the lookup selection values to a subset of related objects based on creiteria that use the record type of the current record (being pedenatic--the filter refers to the record type by name, not `RecordTypeId`, of course), and the value of another field further up the form (`Locality__c`).

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Services__c.service_type__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Services__c.Locality__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Services__c.Default_Location__c}" />
  <apex:inputField required="true" value="{!Services__c.Operated_By__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

This works fine in the standard page layout (when creating a new record through the standard interface) in both creating and editing `Services__c` records. The lookup values in the selection for Operated By are correctly filtered to include only the relevant organisations.

However, when I switch to the VF page, the selection list in the `Operated_By__c` field is empty  when first creating a new record - no options are presented.  It only works for re-editing a record that has already been saved to the database.

My suspicion is that the record type is not being properly initialised for the VF page for a new record.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on here?

Comment: I have observed the same behavior as discussed [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/77636/16491).

Answer (score 3):

I have the solution.

The field for RecordTypeId must be on the page, as an `inputField` (`outputField` is not good enough). It can be hidden with styling, but it has to be there.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!svc.RecordTypeId}" style="display:hidden">
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me but not sure the reason why it was not working with the Output field.

Answer (score 1):

I think your record type gets initialized after the execution of your constructor.

What you can try is write a javascript function in the vf page and call it on window.onload, this javascript function then would call another method - initialize() in your controller extension where you can do the initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Neeraj. Tried that. Didn't work. Same result.

Comment: This was my solution. My page constructor was creating a new blank which overwrote the recordtype that was selected on the previous page. Thanks codeinprogress